# Reactjs avatar src from API

Tags: reactjs

I´m trying to display an avatar on a Modal, 
i have the avatar url on my state:

this.state.example.fields.assignee.avatarUrls.48x48

```
<div>
   <img src='this.state.example.fields.assignee.avatarUrls.48x48'></img>
</div>
```

The image wont appear, i´ve tried with `{{}}`, ``, ...

Comment: should not it be `<img src={this.state.example.fields.assignee.avatarUrls.48x48.png}>`?

Comment: is `48x48.png` a filename or property name?

Comment: Question is not cleared. Try to give sample example. Btw, share your `this.state`

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko, thants the problem! 48x48 is a property!

Comment: @RitwickDey, My state has a lot of other info, and i was trying to make it as simple as possible! Soo on my state `this.state.example.fields.assignee.avatarUrls.48x48` i have this link `https://www.shareicon.net/data/48x48/2015/09/18/103157_man_512x512.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `src` value correctly and access the `48x48` field correctly:

```
<img src={this.state.example.fields.assignee.avatarUrls['48x48']} />
```

Here's a really basic example of showing an image:

```js
class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      imageURL: {
        '48x48': 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/735811/pexels-photo-735811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260'
      }
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return <img src={this.state.imageURL['48x48']} width='500' />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Image />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```